# cancan and inherited_resources overwriting collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, inherited-resources

I think I am running into a conflict with two of my favorite gems.  Consider the following:

```
class AccountsController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def collection
    @accounts ||= end_of_association_chain.order_by(:name.asc).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page =>10)
  end

end
```

It does not seem the CanCan calls the *collection* method.  I feel that it should.

Is there a known work around?  Am I doing something silly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems after lengthy discussion -- that this will not be supported.  Check out this thread for reasoning and work around:  https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/274#comment_888081